# don't get mod_rewrite running under lion

Tags: macos, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So, don't understand what Apache is doing here.

The `rewrite_module` loads and the user's conf allows override

```
<Directory "/Users/me/Sites/">
  Options Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and the `.htaccess` in `/Users/me/Sites/test/.htaccess` says

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~me/test/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

But once I place the `.htaccess` inside `/Users/me/Sites/test/` the server responds with "Forbidden". If I delete the `.htaccess` the contents of `index.php` render.

Any explanations?

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? If using 2.4, then I think you need to use the `Require` directive (`Order`, `Deny`, and `Allow` would be deprecated).

Comment: Server version: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)
    Server built:   Dec 15 2013 18:33:29
    Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:33
    Server loaded:  APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.10
    Compiled using: APR 1.4.2, APR-Util 1.3.10
    Architecture:   64-bit
    Server MPM:     Prefork

Comment: If I put only `RewriteEngine Off` inside the `.htaccess` the contents render as expected. Setting it to `RewriteEngine On` will provocate "Forbidden".

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set `FollowSymlinks` inside the `/etc/apache2/users/me.conf`

```
<Directory "/Users/me/Sites/">
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

A cause would be great.